# Only run if grails target exists

Tags: grails, war

To create a war for a specific env, in grails you do:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=bladdy war
```

It will create even if the specified `grails.env` doesn't exist.  Is there anyway to not allow the grails war command if the grails.env doesn't exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this in a general way because of how `ConfigSlurper` and `ConfigObject` parse configuration files. As the file is parsed the "global" variables are set first, and then the variables for the specified environment are set. There's no way to know what other environments are active because they're not kept in memory. You could manually parse `Config.groovy` but that would be brittle.

But you could add an event callback in `scripts/_Events.groovy` and check for a variable that has no default setting and is only set in an environment block:

```
import grails.util.Environment

eventCreateWarStart = { warName, stagingDir ->
   if (!config.containsKey('someRequiredVar')) {
      println "\nERROR: environment $Environment.current is not valid\n"
      System.exit 1
   }
}
```